# AFNetworking on Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, afnetworking, alamofire

How get JSON data in AFNetworking, Swift?

Code AFNetworking:

```
    let manager = AFHTTPRequestOperationManager()
    manager.responseSerializer = AFHTTPResponseSerializer()

    manager.POST("http://api.address",
    parameters: nil,
        success: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, responseObject: AnyObject!) in

            println("Object: " + responseObject.description)

            if let data = responseObject as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                println("JSON: " + "\(data)")
            } else {
                println("Error JSON")
            }

    },
    failure: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!,error: NSError!) in
        println("Error: " + error.localizedDescription)
    })
```

Result:

Object: < symbols >

Error JSON

Comment: If you are using Swift, than I suggest to implement Alamofire instead of bridging AFNetworking. Find it at : https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire

Comment: 1) I'd rather use https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire for Swift. It is almost the same as AFNetworking but written in Swift by the same authors.
2) manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];//Obj-C code

Comment: Alamofire no support ios 7

Comment: @ZAV Alamofire does support ios 7, I have my app in Swift which uses Alamofire and works fine on ios 7

Comment: It supports IOS 7.0+. chcek readme file of Alamofire. https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire

Comment: @sasquatch Alamofire has the same problem((

Comment: Alamofire supports iOS 7.0+ unless you are not using Cocoapods. If you are using Cocoapods, Swift codes are added as Framework. You can add the library manually.

Comment: @ZAV you are already getting the JSON, the problem is that it can't be cast as `Dictionary<String, AnyObject>`

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Comment: From readme...

    Embedded frameworks require a minimum deployment target of iOS 8 or OS X Mavericks (10.9).

    Alamofire is no longer supported on iOS 7 due to the lack of support for frameworks. Without frameworks, running Travis-CI against iOS 7 would require a second duplicated test target. The separate test suite would need to import all the Swift files and the tests would need to be duplicated and re-written. This split would be too difficult to maintain to ensure the highest possible quality of the Alamofire ecosystem.

Answer (score -1):

I tried it in Alamofire, and it can successfully cast to the Dictionary object.

```
    Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://api.address", parameters: nil, encoding:.JSON).responseJSON
        { response in switch response.result {
        case .Success(let JSON):

            let data = JSON as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>


        case .Failure(let error):
            print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
            }
    }
```